# Why is my program pausing after a selection sort function?

Tags: c++, sorting, selection-sort

I have a simple sorting program being compiled by Dev-C++ 4.9.8.0. I ran the program (yes this compiles) and it simply stops **after** displaying the line where the vector is displayed for the first time. Note - it does not freeze, it seems to just be taking a pause. In the code, the selection sort comes next so I assume that the error happens there, but there is no error message for me to even figure out what to do!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void bubbleSort (vector<int>& data)
{
if(data.size() <= 1)
    return;

int flag=1;
int temp;

   for(int i=1; (i<=data.size()) && flag; i++)
   {
       flag=0;
       for(int j=0; (j<data.size()-1); j++)
       {
           if(data[j+1] > data[j])
           {
               temp = data[j];
               data[j] = data[j+1];
               data[j+1] = temp;
               flag=1;
           }
       }
   }
}

void selectionSort(vector<int>& data)
{
    int min, temp, n=data.size();

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        min = i;

        for (int j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {   
            if (j<min)
            {
                temp=i;
                i=min;
                min=temp;
            }   

        }
    }           
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    vector<int> data;

    cout<<"Vector length?: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        data.push_back(rand()%20+1);
    }

    cout<<"Vector: ";
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<data[i]<<", ";
    }

    selectionSort(data);

    cout<<"Sorted Vector: ";
    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<data[i]<<", ";
    }

    system("Pause");

    return 0;




}
```

Comment: Maybe set `n` to *something* in `selectionSort`. Right now it is indeterminate, yet you're looping on it. `data.size()` seems a decent candidate.

Comment: @WhozCraig But this function runs **after** the user has already entered in a value for n (cin>>n). Therefore, shouldn't it just take that value to use?

Comment: The `n` in `selectionsort` has *nothing* to do with the `n` in `main()`, which is never passed to the function. They're different automatic variables.

Comment: And fyi, your bubble-sort.. isn't a bubble-sort. It is missing swap-detection, a core feature of the algorithm and in-truth the only decent thing about it. It is what gives bubble-sort best-case O(n) on an already sorted sequence.

Comment: and also selection sort is completely wrong. it wont work. even if you set the n in it. You are not even accessing the data in the vector..

Comment: @dingalapadum from the question, I assume `selectionsort` is a work-in-progress, but it at-least-appears the OP thinks bubblesort is finished; it isn't (because it isn't bubblesort).

Comment: selectionSort() method has variable 'n' that is completely a random value that happens to be on the stack at that location. You have a nested loop. Say n is 1982734 or some such arbitrarily large number. You are simply looping over 1982734 * 1982734 times. EVENTUALLY it will complete. Why don't you print the value of 'n' inside selectionSort().

Comment: Oh man... I didn't even realize bubble sort wasn't finished. Wow I actually copied it over from another homework assignment that I turned in last week..........I'll look into this "swap-detection" for it.... In regards to the selection sort - instead of using n can I just use data.size()? I just need the selection sort to recognize that both `i` and `j` must be smaller than the vector size, but based on what you guys are saying `n` in the selection sort is not going to be considered as the same `n` that defines the size of the vector.

Comment: `int min, temp, n = data.size();`

Comment: And a very simple bubblesort using iterators can be seen [**here**](http://ideone.com/Bd58tH). It could have been done better by providing the iterator type as template arguments (see the `print` function for a simple example), but thats probably overkill for what you're trying to do. The output demonstrates that as soon as we detect a pass with no swaps of adjacent elements, we're done. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectionSort() method has variable 'n' that is completely a random value that happens to be on the stack at that location. You haven't initialized it!

You have a nested loop, which is O(n^2). Say n is 1982734 or some such arbitrarily large number. You are simply looping over 1982734 * 1982734 times. EVENTUALLY it will complete. Why don't you print the value of 'n' inside selectionSort(). Just initialize it with the size of the vector.

As others commented this whole work is in progress.